# ReplaceOneAsync does not replace the document

Tags: c#, mongodb

Im' using c# driver to connect to a mongodb database 
I use this code to update a document

```
Mytype new_doc ; 
var filter = Builders<Mytype>.Filter.Eq(c => c.id,
new ObjectId("56f908cbe9dea82560d93fb4"));

var result = await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, cnew_doc, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```

But the document did not changes in th database

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You have bugs in filter. I'm wondering if your code is compiling or not, but assuming `c.id` is MongoDB ObjectId

Replace

```
var filter = Builders<Mytype>.Filter.Eq(c => c.id = "56f908cbe9dea82560d93fb4");
```

With

If `c.id` is MongoDB ObjectId:

```
var filter = Builders<Mytype>.Filter.Eq(c => c.id,
    new ObjectId("56f908cbe9dea82560d93fb4"));
```

Otherwise:

```
var filter = Builders<Mytype>.Filter.Eq(c => c.id, "56f908cbe9dea82560d93fb4");
```

Comment: I replaced but still the same problem . There is a way to test the filter alone ?

Comment: How can I test filter. I'd suggest to update your post along with sample data. Post necessary runnable code to test.

Comment: I tested the filer in a find methode and it's working

Comment: I changed the ReplaceOneAsync() to ReplaceOne and it's working

Comment: That's good. You didn't provided any valid testable code so it's difficult to pinpoint problematic code. simply saying, it's not working is not enough.